# Can't JQuery be served locally on StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request

I'd understand if this question gets flagged but I'll ask it anyway.

I use NoScript on my browser for security. I liked how StackExhange used to serve JavaScript locally (meaning, from StackExchange). Pretty simple...I could just allow StackExchange once and for all. Recently (in the past few weeks, I think) StackExchange has now served JQuery from ajax.googleapis.com. So--for security--I have to "temporarily allow" each and every time I visit StackExchange.

Could JQuery code be served locally? I promise you won't break out in a rash.

Another option is to redesign the site so that functionality won't break if JavaScript isn't available. Yes, obviously interactives like the fancy WYSIWYG editor won't work, but the little "StackExchange" menu in the top left (which is useless without JavaScript) could easily be programmed using CSS (with the fancy animation included!).

Comment: I thought SE had been serving jQuery offsite for quite some time now.

Comment: I use NotScript (NoScript for Chrome), and stackoverflow.com is the only domain that shows up as an option to block... Could be that NoScript catches things that NotScript doesn't, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It has, for many months I'm sure.

Comment: Is permanently accepting jQuery from ajax.googleapis.com not an option? Why? Due to caching, they won't be able to track your movements or anything.

Comment: How about using Greasemonkey on `document-start` to add jQuery into the page, if you're so opposed to allowing ajax.googleapis.com?

Comment: [This is a useful read](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-reasons-why-you-should-be-using-a-cdn-with-wordpress/)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess CDNs have sort of irked me because it seemed to stem from the over-hyped--and under-(security-)analyzed cloud movement. I figure it shouldn't cost anything extra to just serve the script from your page since your page is going to be served anyway. @Joe I also tried going with FoxReplace and loading files from "file://" (which doesn't seem to be something FF is into), but I guess I'll go with your idea. :)